# Installing JRuby 1.6.7 + Rails 3 with Ubuntu?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

Any blog or tutorial for installation of JRuby 1.6.7 and Rails 3 on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First install [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/):

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Once rvm is installed, use it to install jruby:

```
$ rvm install jruby-1.6.7
```

You can then use that version:

```
$ rvm use jruby-1.6.7
```

Finally, install rails:

```
$ jruby -S gem install rails
```

---

**Update**

With more recent versions of rvm, installing the latest version of jruby and rails is [very straightforward](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/):

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby=jruby --gems=rails
```

Comment: With "rvm install jruby-1.7.3", I'm getting "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/db: line 61: awk: command not found" on Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 with openjdk-7. But, it appears that jruby was installed, and I can use jirb.

Comment: One more thing.. the RVM installer mentions that you should use "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"

Comment: @gotqn rvm used to define its variables in `.bash_profile`, so sourcing it was needed to load them.

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec Thanks. Should this be done every time?

Comment: @gotqn No, only the first time rvm was installed — but I believe this is not needed any longer with recent versions of rvm.

Comment: It should be noted that if you use this method and you already have a ruby version installed on your system, your default ruby version will be switched out for whatever one is packaged with JRuby. If you want to switch back to the one you have in the system (because you don't want to switch over to RVM just yet because you're lazy), you can remedy the situation by running the command `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```